# Javascript return a different structur from original array

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array of objects that look like

```
const data: [
    {
      id: 21786162,
      label: "cBTC 2021-06-25 Put $50,000.00",
      active": true,
      type: "put",
      strike_price: 5000000,
      date_live: "2019-11-19 05:00:00+0000",
      date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
      date_exercise: "2021-06-25 21:00:00+0000",
    },
    {
      id: 21786161,
      label: "cBTC 2021-06-25 Call $50,000.00",
      active": true,
      type: "call",
      strike_price: 5000000,
      date_live: "2019-11-19 05:00:00+0000",
      date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
      date_exercise: "2021-06-25 21:00:00+0000",
    },
    {
      id: 21786160,
      label: "cBTC 2021-06-25 Put $25,000.00",
      active": true,
      type: "put",
      strike_price: 2500000,
      date_live: "2019-11-19 05:00:00+0000",
      date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
      date_exercise: "2021-06-25 21:00:00+0000",
    },
    {
      id: 21786159,
      label: "cBTC 2021-06-25 Call $25,000.00",
      active": true,
      type: "call",
      strike_price: 2500000,
      date_live: "2019-11-19 05:00:00+0000",
      date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
      date_exercise: "2021-06-25 21:00:00+0000",
    }....//MORE ITEMS]
```

These items must be grouped by date_expires and strike_price. Then have a way to differentiate whatever the item is a put or call type.

What I want to end up is a data structure that look like the below:

```
const data = [
    {
        date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
        strike_price: 5000000,
        put:  {
            id: 21786162,
            label: "cBTC 2021-06-25 Put $50,000.00",
            active: true,
            type: "put",
            strike_price: 5000000,
            date_live: "2019-11-19 05:00:00+0000",
            date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
            date_exercise: "2021-06-25 21:00:00+0000",
        },
         call: {
            id: 21786161,
            label: "cBTC 2021-06-25 Call $50,000.00",
            active: true,
            type: "call",
            strike_price: 5000000,
            date_live: "2019-11-19 05:00:00+0000",
            date_expires: "2021-06-25 20:00:00+0000",
            date_exercise: "2021-06-25 21:00:00+0000",
        },
    },
    {
        date_expires: "2020-09-25 20:00:00+0000",
        strike_price: 1500000,
        put: {
    `       id: 22199400,
            label: "cBTC 2020-09-25 Put $15,000.00",
            active: true,
            type: "put",
            strike_price: 1500000,
            date_live: "2020-03-27 04:00:00+0000",
            date_expires: "2020-09-25 20:00:00+0000",
            date_exercise: "2020-09-25 21:00:00+0000",
        },`
        call: {
            id: 22199399,
            label: "cBTC 2020-09-25 Call $15,000.00",
            active: true,
            type: "call",
            strike_price: 1500000,
            date_live: "2020-03-27 04:00:00+0000",
            date_expires: "2020-09-25 20:00:00+0000",
            date_exercise: "2020-09-25 21:00:00+0000",
        },
    }.....
]
```

I managed to have a working solution but the code seems a bit sloppy I was wondering if I could improve it (I am open to use Map or other datas structures).

My solution:

```
 function groupBy(array, f) {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach(function (o) {
      var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
      groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
      groups[group].push(o);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function (group) {
      return groups[group];
    });
  }


    const grouped = groupBy(contracts, function (item) {
          return [item.date_expires, item.strike_price];
        });

        const final = grouped.map((el) => {
          const result = {
            date_expires: el[0].date_expires,
            strike_price: el[0].strike_price,
          };

          if (el[0].type === 'put') {
            result.put = el[0];
            result.call = el[1];
          } else if (el[0].type === 'call') {
            result.put = el[1];
            result.call = el[0];
          }

          return result;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code can be improved a bit through making a few small improvements for readability, namingly using `Object.values`, `for..of`, also your groupBy could directly support merging:

```
  const toArray = (prev = [], el) => prev.concat(el);

  function groupBy(array, getKey, merge = toArray) {
    const groups = {};
    for(const el of array) {
      const key = JSON.stringify(getKey(el));
      groups[key] = merge(groups[key], el);
    }
   return Object.values(groups);
 }
```

With that, your code turns into:

```
 const result = groupBy(
   data,
   it => [it.date_expires, it.strike_price],
   (group = {}, { date_price, strike_price, ...el}) => ({ ...group, date_price, strike_price, [el.type]: el })
 );
```

Is that actually *better*? Well, that pretty much depends on your view.